# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity and android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15

Tags: java, runtimeexception, inflate-exception

I am currently working on an app which uses fragments for which I have taken the standard fragment activity available in android studio. This is a frequently asked question but I am unable to solve my error with the solutions provided. Please help me find a solution to this problem.
The app shows error and does not even start. The start activity is the same which is indicated in the logcat.

This is the logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.aryan.productmanagement, PID: 12109
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aryan.productmanagement/com.aryan.productmanagement.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15 in com.aryan.productmanagement:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #19 in com.aryan.productmanagement:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3645)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
                                                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15 in com.aryan.productmanagement:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #19 in com.aryan.productmanagement:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19 in com.aryan.productmanagement:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment HomeFragment{8989f78} (73776694-1cbb-4344-8de7-b00f8c2088b4 id=0x7f080138) did not return a View from onCreateView() or this was called before onCreateView().
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireView(Fragment.java:2063)
                                                                                                        at com.aryan.productmanagement.activities.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:46)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3104)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:524)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1433)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2977)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2888)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3129)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:394)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:260)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:142)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:136)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:248)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:227)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1073)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1267)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1267)
2024-03-07 11:37:12.607 12109-12109 AndroidRuntime          com.aryan.productmanagement          E      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
                                                                                                        at com.aryan.productmanagement.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:53)
                                                                                                        at com.aryan.productmanagement.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:47)
                                                                                                        at com.aryan.productmanagement.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8305)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8284)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1417)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3626)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

It refers to the following XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_main"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

According to this my 15th line is
        `android:layout_height="match_parent" />`
and my 19th line is
        `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`
The logcat refers these lines but I can't understand the problem here!

The java file of the same is

```
package com.aryan.productmanagement;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.aryan.productmanagement.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_uploadproduct, R.id.nav_stock)
                .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

I tried majority of the solutions on the forum but could not find a solution to this problem